# How can I ensure the RSS data without repetition when fetch RSS data

Tags: web, rss, rss-reader

As we know, the RSS data will update if the website manager update it, or the third-part lib to update the RSS feed data.

Now if I am writing a RSS Reader, every time I fetch the data from the website's RSS source.

How can I ensure the data whether is fetched?

From the [wikipedia RSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) :

[image]

Only the `title`, `link`, `description` fields are required. the `pubDate` is not required. So, I can not insure the data whether is fetched by us via `pubDate` or other fields(like `lastBuildDate` field).

So, which friend can tell me how do you verify the feed data whether is fetched by us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the link can ensure a item whether is fetched.

I can save the fetched data in my database, every time the user fetch data, it can check the data whether is exists in the database by `link` property.

Answer (score 0):

When reading an RSS feed, the `guid` element of each item is used to check whether the item has been read before.

A `guid` can be a permalink to the HTML version of the item, like this:

```
<guid>http://dallas.example.com/1983/05/06/joebob.htm</guid>
```

A `guid` also can be any other text that provides a unique value for an item, such as one using the [TAG URI](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc4151.html) specification, as in this example:

```
<guid isPermaLink="false">tag:dallas.example.com,4131:news</guid>
```

Although the name `guid` stands for Globally Unique ID, there is no requirement in RSS for a `guid` value to be globally unique. At most you can hope that it will be unique for that feed publisher.

The `guid` element is optional.

Comment: its option. i can not ensure the publisher give it.